# How to show that a line between any two points in an ellipse remains entirely inside the ellipse

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that for any two points say $x,y$ inside some ellipses centered at the origin, say $\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b} = 1$, the line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ is also contained in the ellipse.

Intuitively, this seems obvious but I am having trouble trying to prove it.

I was thinking of the following approach:

Fix $x,y$ in the ellipse. Since the interior of the ellipse is open, there is some $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)$ is contained in the ellipse. Hence, we get that all points on the line from $x$ to $y$ which are a distance $r$ from $x$ are also in $x$. Also for the point on the line where the distance between the point and $x$ is equal to $r$, there is another positive number such that the ball centered at this point is contained in the ellipse. Continuing like this I was hoping to cover the entire line.

But I am not sure we are guaranteed that this approach will cover the line since the successive choices for the radius of the balls could converge to $0$ and so we may not cover the line.

Is there anyway to make this argument correct? I am thinking that maybe we can use the compactness of the line segment here.

Or is there a better argument altogether?

Comment: If you know it's true for a circle, a stretching/scaling argument gives you the ellipse case for free.

Comment: If your approach was valid, it would apply to _any_ open set, wouldn't it? So it can't be valid.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the chord between $[\theta]$ and $[\phi]$ is
$$(x,y)=\lambda (a\cos \theta,b\sin \theta)+
(1-\lambda)(a\cos \phi,b\sin \phi)$$

where $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Now

\begin{align*}
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} &=
  [\lambda \cos \theta+(1-\lambda) \cos \phi]^2+
  [\lambda \sin \theta+(1-\lambda) \sin \phi]^2 \\
  &= \lambda^2+(1-\lambda)^2+2\lambda (1-\lambda)\cos (\theta-\phi)
\end{align*}

Note that $\lambda(1-\lambda) \ge 0$ and $\cos (\theta-\phi) \le 1$, so

\begin{align*}
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} &\le \lambda^2+(1-\lambda)^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda) \\
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} &\le 1
\end{align*}

For $\theta-\phi \ne 2n\pi$, equality holds only when $\lambda=0$ or $1$.

Hence the chord is at the interior of the ellipse.